# How to know the difference between the distributed Ubuntu image and Docker Ubuntu image

Tags: docker

In the ubuntu docker image, it seems that some changes have been made to the docker image.
For example, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean` has been added.
I believe these operations are included in the official image
[github.com/multiarch/ubuntu-core/blob/master/update.sh#L72-L91](https://github.com/multiarch/ubuntu-core/blob/master/update.sh#L72-L91)

Where can I find out what changes the ubuntu docker image makes to the officially distributed ubuntu image?

Comment: To start off, the Docker image doesn't even have `systemd`...

Comment: Unofficial/downstream remixes and customizations, including "*the ubuntu docker image*" must provide their own support. They are off-topic here. We don't keep track of their myriad changes.

Comment: @user535733 Docker Ubuntu is actually an official flavor of Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/security/docker-images

Comment: @DanielT The OP specifically linked to an unofficial github repo, and explicitly mistook that repo to be official. While Canonical's Ubuntu Docker is not a [real flavor](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours), it is a real Ubuntu derivative by the same development team so it's support here is a gray area best discussed in meta (like Pro or LXD or other non-flavor Canonical products).

Answer (score 0):

As somebody who is just learning Docker, I will tell you than an official image will not have any changes aside from those required to run it in the Docker container.  I read the description of the container on Docker Hub and it mentions no changes.  Since it is from Canonical you should be able to trust that.  I will warn you though, make sure you know docker before setting anything up on that image if you run it.  Starting over is NEVER fun on Docker.

Comment: Post-Invoke changes the behavior when using cache. 
I want to know what changes have been made to the file in image.

Comment: I'm still learning, but from what I know at this point your only real option is to spin one up as a test and go in to look.  But I also don't know how you'd find everything that way either. Sorry I can't help more.